# Project requires reference to Entity Framework but it shouldn't

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm fighting a weirdly unexpected issue with references. There are two two projects: *Model* and *Handler*. The former has a reference to EF (as it should) and so does the latter. Of course, *Model* provides the model information and it's referenced by *Handler*.

Obviously, it seems to be unnecessary to have a reference to EF in *Handler*, as it should get it's knowledge about it via the referenced *Model* project. So I removed the references to EF from it.

To my surprise, VS barked at me and demanded EF to be referenced in **both** the projects! Why is it so and is it supposed to be like that?!

Please note that removing the references to both *Model* and EF makes the names of the classes in defined in my model red (as supposed to) and referencing *Model* back into *Handler* turns them green. However, even then, I get this red underline requiring me to reference EF too. I don't get it...

Comment: Add the reference back to EF, use the function "Find Code Dependent On Module" by clicking the referenced assembly in the References list. This will give you a list of code segments where EF is referenced. And, maybe post some code if you want more extensive help :P

Comment: Are you referencing the `Model` _project_ or _assembly_?

Comment: In which project is your edmx located

Comment: @FabioSalvalai It's in *Model*.

Comment: @DStanley Whatever is done automatically based on VS's and Resharper's suggestion. I'm fairly sure it's the assembly.

Comment: @Marcus I'll check it out right away. As for the code - not sure which part to show. The whole project is rather big and I'm unsure which parts are relevant to this issue. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using POCO for your models ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using POCO objects, your Entity objects all inherit from [`ObjectContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

This object is declared in the assembly `System.Data.Entity`, therefore any project that uses one of your entities will require a reference to that assembly.

Comment: Well, we're using EF so all the types are generated based on the database schema. I'm not sure if that's POCO enough, though. Still, the question that puzzles us is that the reference should be in the project that creates the types. Then, we should have a reference to it from the second project and that 's it. I can't see why we need to re-reference the EF library all over again. What do I miss?!

Comment: Well, if you're using generated types, they probably inherit from ObjectContext (you can verify this) therefore, they are not just plain old CLR objects, they inherit from a base class which contains EF-specific logic. In order to be able to leverage this logic, the consuming code need to know the whole hierarchy of your model objects, and therefore, needs to reference EF to be able to use ObjectContext's methods.

Comment: I wonder why the knowledge of the hierarchy isn't implicitly known already, after I've referenced the stuff from the second project that has references to EF.

Comment: because the base object, and its logic, is not included in the second project. maybe you don't _use_ that logic, but the compiler has no way to know that. I think - yet i'm not 100% sure - you can get rid of the dependency if you don't use this logic, you could have interfaces in your second project, modify the .tt files to generate object that implement these interfaces, and code against the interfaces in your _Handler_ project -> To Be Confirmed.

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining the question wrongly. All the TT files and objects are in the *Model* project (and it references EF). The project called *Handler* **uses** the entities but it learns about them by referencing the project *Model*. In fact, when you hover over the class names, you can see that those are from the namespace of the *Model*. So, why is the reference to EF required even in *Handler*?! Maybe I'm stupid or dense but I can't can't see why...

Comment: The reference is needed because, if I understand correctly, the classes which are generated by your t4 templates inherit from an EF-specific base class. Is that correct? Now, your generated classes merely _extend_ these EF classes, they don't hide them, and therefore, the base class' assembly is also needed in the consuming project, the handler. Note that the Models project alone is not enough, they are just the extension of an EF object. If handler doesn't understand the whole hierarchy of an object's classes, it can't work with it, does it make sense? Sorry, if I'm not very clear.

Comment: And don't worry about asking questions, if I can answer, I'm glad to help :)

Comment: Got it. You've already got the reply accepted as the correct answer and you've been awarded +1 for persistence. Nice!